# Use dplyr package and %>% function instead of data frame indexing

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
data <- data.frame(name = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "B", "C", "C"),
                   id = c(1, 2, NA, 3, 4, NA, 5, 6, 7, NA, 8, 9, 10, 11))
```

What I want to do is to replace each of the `NAs` in the `id` column with a unique 3-digit number. The way I do it is as follows:

```
data$id[is.na(data$id)] <- sample(100:999, size = sum(is.na(data$id)), replace = F)
```

Is there a way to do this using the `dplyr` package and specifically the `%>%` function? Something like that:

```
data %>% mutate(...)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Brief explanation why I deleted my answer: `ifelse` fundamentally doesn’t work here since it expects all arguments to have the same length. Since the `sample()` output has length 3 instead of length 14, R recycles the values. The only solution that I can think of would involve a temporary data.frame which has filtered all NA rows (which is verbose and inefficient and, IMHO, plain unacceptable). This is a long-standing deficiency in ‘dplyr’: for many years, users have requested a `mutate_when` function which would solve this, but this still hasn’t been added to ‘dplyr’ yet.

Comment: @KonradRudolph do you also know how does this cause some values to be the same, while some of them still get a unique value? (like in your deleted code)

Comment: @bird That’s the point: it’s because R recycles the values. Let’s say we did `sample(1 : 3, 3)` and got the numbers `c(1, 2, 3)` back. R now recycles these numbers to length 14 (the number of rows in your table): `c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2)`. And then it selects the indices which correspond to the NAs in the `id` column: 3, 6 and 10. Which happen to be: `c(3, 3, 1)`. That’s why you get duplicate results.

Comment: Maybe `mutate(id = replace(id, is.na(id), sample(100:1000, size = sum(is.na(id)), replace = FALSE)))`

Comment: @Henrik Excellent, that does it. Please write an answer.

Comment: Presumably you mean `100:999`, not `100:1000`

Comment: @HongOoi Yes, 100:999.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the solution @Henrik wrote on the comments below my answer. If he posts his answer, I'll delete this one.

```
data %>% mutate(id = replace(id, is.na(id), sample(100:999, size = sum(is.na(id)), replace = FALSE)))
```

Answer (score 1):

**tidyverse**

```
library(tidyverse)
data <-
  data.frame(name = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "B", "C", "C"),
             id = c(1, 2, NA, 3, 4, NA, 5, 6, 7, NA, 8, 9, 10, 11)) %>% 
  rowid_to_column()

tmp <- data %>% 
  filter(is.na(id)) %>% 
  mutate(id = sample(100:1000, size = sum(is.na(id)), replace = FALSE))

res <- rows_update(data, tmp, by = "rowid") %>% 
  select(-rowid)
res
#>    name  id
#> 1     A   1
#> 2     A   2
#> 3     A 859
#> 4     B   3
#> 5     B   4
#> 6     C 121
#> 7     D   5
#> 8     D   6
#> 9     D   7
#> 10    D 730
#> 11    E   8
#> 12    B   9
#> 13    C  10
#> 14    C  11
```

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)
data <-
  data.frame(name = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "B", "C", "C"),
             id = c(1, 2, NA, 3, 4, NA, 5, 6, 7, NA, 8, 9, 10, 11))
setDT(data)[is.na(id), id := sample(100:1000, size = sum(is.na(id)), replace = FALSE)][]
#>     name  id
#>  1:    A   1
#>  2:    A   2
#>  3:    A 234
#>  4:    B   3
#>  5:    B   4
#>  6:    C 636
#>  7:    D   5
#>  8:    D   6
#>  9:    D   7
#> 10:    D 617
#> 11:    E   8
#> 12:    B   9
#> 13:    C  10
#> 14:    C  11
```

Comment: OP wants unique 3 digit number, but `100:1000` contains `1000` as well (in OP's original code as well). This means there is a small chance that one of the `NA`s could be filled with a 4 digit number. I think OP meant to say `100:999`

Answer (score -1):

Add to Rudoplh's code

```
na_len = length(is.na(data))
na_len

data2 <- data %>%
  mutate(id = ifelse(is.na(id), sample(100:1000, size = na_len, replace = FALSE), id))
data2
```

this give us unfixed imputated numbers

Comment: `length(is.na(data))` isn’t the correct value.